# Optimum Regular Expression

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a hypothetical path for which I want a simple PCRE regular expression. For the purpose of simplicity, let's assume it is three levels deep and that each folder's name is A, B and C respectively.

The following items should match the expression:

```
A
AB
ABC
```

The following items should *not* match the expression:

```
AC
ACB
B
BA
BAC
BC
BCA
C
CA
CAB
CB
CBA
```

The only expression I can conjure is

```
^**A**(**B**(**C**)?)?$
```

However, ideally I would like something where the right side of the pattern is not dependent on the depth (which might be much greater than 3). 
i.e. `^**A**\1**B**\1**C**$`

Note that I'm aware the the above is an invalid pattern, but I hope it illustrates my point.

I've messed around with back-references etc. but just can't seem to crack it. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to communicate with the (invalid) regex `^**A**(**B**(**C**)?)?$`. What do the `**` parts mean? English may be a better choice for description than pseudo-regex

Comment: You want `^(A|AB|ABC)$` or `^(A(BC?)?)$`

Answer (score 2):

Although these

```
^(A|AB|ABC)$
^(A(BC?)?)$
```

solve your problem as described (thank you to [ctwheels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3600709/ctwheels) for the second option, which is more efficient), this may be closer to what you seek:

```
^A((?<=A)B)?((?<=B)C)?$
```

which means "A, then optionally B but only if it follows A, then optionally C but only if it follows B", because it can be built up programatically using simple iteration over an arbitrarily long list of values. Other than the first term, each part is made of

```
((?<=PREVIOUS)NEXT)?
```

Comment: You can add `^(A(BC?)?)$` to your answer if you want too. No point in me adding a whole separate answer (it's the method with least amount of steps)